# ScrollView inside ConstraintLayout not scrolling entirely to the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I had to introduce a `ScrollView` in my `Dialog` layout to display all the layout when the phone is in landscape mode or the app is running on small screens. However, the bottom of the layout is being cut off.

I've tried different things like setting `ScrollView`'s `layout_height = "0dp"`, adding more constraints, replacing the `ScrollView` with a `NestedScrollView` and other small things as `clipToPadding = false` or `fillViewPort = true` but none of these have worked.

This is my layout currently used in a `Dialog` I need:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon_image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_help_outline_white_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/message_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_image_container">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_example_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:text="@string/help_dialog_example_title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_message" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_example_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_example_title" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help_button_ok"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:text="@string/help_dialog_button_ok"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_example_message" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

And this is how it's being displayed with the above xml layout. The image is showing the scrollview scrolled to the bottom as far as possible.

[image: current layout]

I have been stuck on this a lot. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You should consider using linearlayout for this vertical layout!

Comment: Can you share text content So i can try your issue.

Comment: Oh it was so simple! Thank you @SumitShukla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post the answer in case anybody encounter the same issue. I just replaced the root layout from `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout` with `orientation = "vertical"` and the same thing for the layout inside the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

Change scrollview height to 0dp and constraint it to the bottom of parent it should solve your issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/icon_image_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_help_outline_white_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/message_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_image_container">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/help_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/help_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/help_example_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
            android:text="@string/help_dialog_example_title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_message" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/help_example_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_example_title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/help_button_ok"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/help_dialog_button_ok"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/help_example_message" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried this before but didn't solve my issue. I have posted the solution now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon_image_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_help_outline_white_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/message_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_image_container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_example_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:text="@string/help_dialog_example_title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/help_example_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/help_button_ok"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/internal_margin_views"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:text="@string/help_dialog_button_ok"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @Automatik try this.